# How to update state on disabled field in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to showing default value and want to disable it field . Values is showing successfully but did not update it state . Could someone please help me how to update state on disable field . I really tried hard but didn't find any solution .

Thanks

**Code**

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { projectData } = nextProps;
    this.setState({
      project: projectData,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { stan_rate_Per_sqft, category_charges, project } = this.state;

    console.log("@@@@@ data", stan_rate_Per_sqft, category_charges);
    if (
      project &&
      project.category_charges_apply &&
      project.category_charges_apply === "yes"
    ) {
      this.setState({
        rate_Per_sqft: stan_rate_Per_sqft * parseInt(1 + category_charges),
      });
    }
  }
```

In Render Method

```
 <td>
       <input
        type="text"
        className="inputStyle"
        name="rate_Per_sqft"
        value={rate_Per_sqft}
        disabled={true}
       placeholder="Category Charges"
    />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component is always disabled since it's hardcoded to `true`. If you want it to have a dynamic state you'll need to add key to your class state.

```
...

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isDisabled: true }
}

...
```

Now, in your input field, you may use this state...

```
<input ... disabled={this.state.isDisabled} />
```

When isDisabled is set to false (using setState), the field will be enabled again and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefdisabled) attribute on an `<input>` element works by passing in a boolean value. A truthy value will disable it, a falsy value will enable it.

With that in mind we could use the negated value of `rate_Per_sqft` to enable the input element. Perhaps something like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    rate_Per_sqft: null
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    // Simulate asynchronous operation
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ rate_Per_sqft: 550 })
    }, 1500)
  }


  render() {
    const { rate_Per_sqft } = this.state
    
    return(
      <div>
       {!rate_Per_sqft && <span>Calculating charges..</span>}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="rate_Per_sqft"
          value={rate_Per_sqft}
          disabled={!rate_Per_sqft}
          placeholder="Category Charges"
        />
      </div>
    )

  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Note: I wasn't sure if you wanted the form disabled or enabled by default. So, I disabled it. Also, I simplified the code to keep the example short and simple.